# Is HP 6623A Linear or Switching power supply?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, linear

I have an [HP 6623A](https://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/5957-6377.pdf)  DC power supply and i wonder if its Linear or Switching power supply.
I see in the manual it says linear, but i still wonder.

Why i am asking:
I am asking this, becouse after probing my circuit, i noticed noise of 5MHz (680mV peak to peak) when current is drawn from this power supply, and also the amplitide of the noise increased as i increased the output voltage of the supply.

Using another power supply which is linear on the same configuration did not produce that noise (i only get 20mV peak-to-peak).

Here a picture of my oscilloscope with that noise:
[image: noise]

And yes, i probed my circuit the right way:
[image: probe]

EDIT:
Added schematic.

Also, the supply says Calibration done: 8-Jan-2010, and the next is due to 2011.
So it is at least 10 years old, and not calibrated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhcbMJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is specified Vpp voltage noise and how much did you get from measurement?

Comment: What is the load? Is is set for Remote Sensing? If yes, did you connect to the Remote Sensing inputs? It will have a weak default Remote Sensing connection that may be susceptible to noise.

Comment: What is the manufacture date? It could be 30 years old. HP/Agilent use high quality components but electrolytics will fail eventually.

Comment: I added the replies to my edit.
Its not remote sensing. Vpp is 680mV, and with my other supply i get 20mV Vpp.
I dont know the Manufacture date, but the last time it was calibrated was at 2010.

Comment: It should have a manufacture date on the back.

Comment: What is that schematic? You should test with a resistive load only.

Comment: If it's branded as HP rather than Agilent or Keysight, it's at least 20 years old.

Comment: Get the schematics/repair manual somehow and change all the electrolytic capacitors with new same or better quality. You can still sell as is on eBay if you don't want to repair it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely a linear power supply.  As described in the manual, it uses transistors as linear pass elements to regulate the output voltage. No switching elements are used. As far as noise is concerned, the manual specifies a value of 3 mv P-P for PARD (periodic and random deviation) over a 20 MHz bandwidth. If this is being exceeded, then there is a good chance that the filter capacitors are probably in need of replacement.